# Vectorial function and parametrics

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Calculate $\int_C F·dr$ with $F=(e^y+ye^x, xe^y+e^x)$ where C is the path from $(a,0)$ to $(-a,0)$ over the upper half of the ellipse $b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$.

So $x=a\sin(t)$ and $y=bcos(t)$, then $r(t)=(a\sin(t), b\cos(t))$ and $r'(t)=(a\cos(t),-b\sin(t))$

Then $$F(t)=(e^{b\cos(t)}+b\cos(t)e^{a\sin(t)},a\sin(t)e^{b\cos(t)}+e^{a\sin(t)})$$

Then we have:

$$\int_0^\pi a\cos(t)e^{b\cos(t)}+abcos^2(t)e^{a\sin(t)}-absin^2(t)e^{b\cos(t)}-b\sin(t)e^{a\sin(t)} dt.$$

But the problem here is how to solve the integral, but we know that the answer is -2a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your life too hard -- this is a conservative vector field!  Notice that
$$
\vec{F}=\nabla G,\qquad G(x,y):=xe^y+ye^x.
$$
So, EVERY route from $(a,0)$ to $(-a,0)$ will have the same integral, and that integral is precisely
$$
G(-a, 0)-G(a,0)=(-ae^0+0e^{-a})-(ae^0+0e^a)=-2a.
$$